# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. (Next)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

There is my problem:
I want to show my github repos on a react componant but I've got the error: **Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

There is my code:

```
import styles from "../styles/index.module.scss";
import { getRepos } from "../scripts/github";

export default async function Home() {
  try {
    const repos = await getRepos()
    const hrefelement = repos.map(repo => <><p><a href={repo.homepage as string} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{repo.name}</a></p></>)
  
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1>diamant.dev</h1>
        <div className={styles.repos}>
          {hrefelement}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1>diamant.dev</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and the [`github.ts`](https://pastebin.com/WkGtU7zZ) file:

```
const githubUsername = 'diamantdev'
const githubUrl = `https://api.github.com/users/${githubUsername}/repos`

export const getRepos = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(githubUrl);
    const repos: [Repos] = await response.json();
    const sortedRepos = repos.sort()
    return sortedRepos.filter((repo) => repo.name != githubUsername || !repo.archived)
}
```

Comment: You should make api call in useEffect hook. And after you get response, store that response in state of component and use  that state to render

Comment: I suspect it's because of `async function Home`, and I don't think your component can be an async function. Instead, I recommend learning about the `useEffect` and `useState` hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

```
export default async function Home() {
```

Components cannot be `async`. The standard approach for loading data is to have state for your data, which starts empty. You render once with that empty data (either rendering null or a placeholder), then fetch, then rerender once you have the data.

```
export default function Home() {
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [repos, setRepos] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      try {
        const repos = await getRepos();
        setRepos(repos);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
      }
    }
    fetch();
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1>diamant.dev</h1>
      </div>
    )
  } else if (repos) {
      return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1>diamant.dev</h1>
        <div className={styles.repos}>
          {hrefelement}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    // still loading
    return null
  }
}
```